# Load Properties into the application only once through out the whole application

Tags: java, initialization

I am loading Properties from a file in my Java application using the following code

```
    private Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/config.properties");
    private Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
    private List<String> connectionParameters = Arrays.asList(properties.getProperty("connection").split(","));
```

But I dont want this code to be called again once I load the properties into connectionParameters I do not want the loading logic to be called again and I want the list to be alive and available as long as the application is alive.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply convert those fields into **static fields** to ensure that they will be initialized only once **on class initialization** as next:

```
private static final Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/config.properties");
private static final Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(
    resource
);
private static final List<String> connectionParameters = Arrays.asList(
    properties.getProperty("connection").split(",")
);
```

Indeed **static** fields and **static** blocks are initialized/executed only once when the class is initialized by the `ClassLoader`.

Comment: But every time the class instance is created, wouldn't that piece of code be called again?

Comment: no only when the class will be loaded by the ClassLoader for the very first time

Answer (score 5):

You might use a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and load it just once.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks. Even the other answer makes sense and is more convenient  to use. :-) Upvoted.